# dictionary in java using java.io

Tags: java, dictionary, java-io

I have written code of dictionary in java in which i read data from file named newFile.txt .In file world is placed on one line and its meaning is placed on nextline. User enters a world. If word is found in file it shows its meaning placed on next line and if word is not found it shows similar words (substrings).

> "While searching word it should not search meaning."

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Notepad {
    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader in = null;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str;
        boolean notfound = false;
        char again = 'a';

        try{
            do{
                notfound = false;
                System.out.println("Enter word :");
                str = input.next();
                File f = new File("D:\\newFile.txt");
                in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                String s;

                while((s = in.readLine()) != null){

                    int x = s.indexOf(str);

                    if(x != -1){
                        int lens = s.length();
                        String sub = s.substring(x);
                        int lensub = str.length();
                        if(lens == lensub){
                            System.out.println((in.readLine()));
                            break;
                        }
                        else{
                            System.out.println(sub) ;
                            notfound = true;
                        }
                    }
                    s = in.readLine();
                }
                if(!notfound){
                    System.out.println("Try another world?(y/n):");
                    again = input.next().trim().charAt(0);
                    again = Character.toLowerCase(again);
                }
            }
            while(notfound || again == 'y');
            System.out.println("terminated!");
        }
        finally{
            if(in != null){
                in.close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

when i enters a substring of a word it searches meaning as well and then if a enter right word it does not show meaning

Comment: i do not have a dictionary to find the meaning of your question

Comment: I guess the question is how filter out the meanings from the word search. If so, by building on your current solution, you could keep a counter of the line numbers.

Comment: when i enters a substring of a word it searches meaning as well and then if a enter right word it does not show meaning

Comment: I ran your code and I think I am understanding what is going on, how is your newFile.txt set up. In my file I have like "Hello - a greeting word" is that similar to yours?

Comment: Word on one line and its meaning on next line

Comment: @Ayesha Answer was editted

Answer (score 1):

//This code is reading a file that is situated like this:

```
Hello - to greet
Circle - a round shape
```

//Then the code can be done like so, is this ok?

```
  public static void main(String []args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader in = null;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str;
        boolean notfound = false;
        char again = 'a';

        try{
            do{
                notfound = false;
                System.out.println("Enter word :");
                str = input.next();
                File f = new File("/Folder/demo1.txt");
                in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                String s;

                while((s = in.readLine()) != null){

                    int x = s.indexOf(str);
                 //   System.out.println("Index of dash:" + s.indexOf("-"));
                 //   System.out.println("Index of Hello:" + x);

                    if(x != -1 && x<s.indexOf("-")){

                        String sub = s.substring(0,s.indexOf("-"));
                        System.out.println("Sub:" + sub);
                        System.out.println("Str:" + str);
                        if(sub.trim().equals(str.trim())){
                              System.out.println("Success:" +sub);
                               notfound = true;
                               break;


                        }

                        else{
                            System.out.println("Word is not present") ;
                            notfound = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }



                }
                if(!notfound){
                    System.out.println("Try another word?(y/n):");
                    again = input.next().trim().charAt(0);
                    again = Character.toLowerCase(again);
                }
            }
            while(notfound || again == 'y');
            System.out.println("terminated!");
        }
        finally{
            if(in != null){
                in.close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is not the issue. To skip a line i have used readline() twice

Comment: @Ayesha yes i did run it but I took " s = in.readLine();" out before I paste it here. I edited my answer again

Comment: @Ayesha actually I am going take that line back out because it doesn't work properly with it. The other way actually worked it just needs to break when it successfully finds the word except looping to the next one. I edited my answer and inputted the break

Comment: @Ayesha I also took out my unnecessary print statements that my have been confusing